# Entity Framework Select Items Position In Ordered list

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I want to select the position of a user in an ordered list.

I could only get it to work by loading all items into memory and then using `IndexAt()` method to find the position. However this does not work really well when having many rows in the database.

```
        public static async Task<int> GetUsersRank(DbEntities db, string userId)
    {           
      var items = await db.UserIqAnswers.Where(x => x.IqQuestion.CorrectAnswer == x.Answer).GroupBy(x => x.UserId).Select(x => new { userId = x.Key, points = x.Sum(y => y.IqQuestion.Points) })
         .OrderBy(x => x.points)
         .ToListAsync();
      return items.FindIndex(x => x.userId == userId) + 1;         
    }
```

How could I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?
This will run two queries. One to load the info for the current user, and another to load the position in the list.
The queries should be fairly efficient, though. The second one should be done as a COUNT() on the SQL server side.

```
var sumByUser = db.UserIqAnswers.Where(x => x.IqQuestion.CorrectAnswer == x.Answer)
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
    .Select(x => new { userId = x.Key, points = x.Sum(y => y.IqQuestion.Points) });
var currentUser = sumByUser.Where(x => x.userId == userId).Single();
var rank = sumByUser.Where(x => x.points > currentUser.points).Count();
```

Note that the 'sumByUser' query is never executed, it's just used as a base for the next two queries.

You could maybe rewrite this to run as one query by using LINQ syntax:

```
(from currentUser in sumByUser.Where(x => x.userId == userId)
 from rank in sumByUser.Where(x => x.points > currentUser.points
 select new { currentUser, rank = rank.Count()}).Single()
```

But I would inspect the generated SQL on that one to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by gnud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983326/entity-framework-select-items-position-in-ordered-list/40983553#40983553) presented the right idea, but unfortunately both provided solutions do not translate well to SQL. It's because EF6 query translation still is sensitive to the way you write the LINQ queries (unfortunately).

Here is an implementation (found by experimenting) that produces a good translation (change the `decimal?` cast to the nullable type of the `Points` property type - the cast is needed to avoid NRE in case the set is empty):

```
public static async Task<int> GetUsersRank(DbEntities db, string userId)
{
    var userPoints = await db.UserIqAnswers
        .Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.IqQuestion.CorrectAnswer == x.Answer)
        .SumAsync(x => (decimal?)x.IqQuestion.Points) ?? 0;

    var rank = await db.UserIqAnswers
        .Select(x => new { x.UserId, x.Answer, x.IqQuestion })
        .Where(x => x.UserId != userId && x.IqQuestion.CorrectAnswer == x.Answer)
        .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
        .Select(x => new { userId = x.Key, points = x.Sum(y => y.IqQuestion.Points) })
        .CountAsync(x => x.points < userPoints || (x.points == userPoints && string.Compare(x.userId, userId) < 0));

    return rank;
}
```

which generates 2 SQLs like this:

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        SUM([Extent2].[Points]) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[UserIqAnswers] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[IqQuestions] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[Answer] = [Extent2].[CorrectAnswer]) AND ([Extent1].[IqQuestion_Id] = [Extent2].[Id])
        WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

and

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent1].[UserId] AS [K1],
            SUM([Extent2].[Points]) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[UserIqAnswers] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[IqQuestions] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[IqQuestion_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]) AND ([Extent2].[CorrectAnswer] = [Extent1].[Answer])
            WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] <> @p__linq__0
            GROUP BY [Extent1].[UserId]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
        WHERE ([GroupBy1].[A1] < @p__linq__1) OR (([GroupBy1].[A1] = @p__linq__2) AND ([GroupBy1].[K1] < @p__linq__3))
    )  AS [GroupBy2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb738680(v=vs.110).aspx)**: To take element 501 ..

```
queryable.Skip(500).Take(1).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't help you find the position of an element though. This will only help you if you already know the position of the element you want.

Comment: @gnud You are right I understand the question backward.